# php - how to use the echo in select where parameter?

Tags: php, sql, echo

I want to use the string   ( echo $row['en'];  ) 
in the select command in the where parameter of subject :

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM uploaded WHERE sbid='".$newid."' AND subject = **HERE** ;
```

and thanks :)

Comment: ...and? You're already using `$newid`, why can't you use `$row['en']` the same way?

Comment: because its value will be change every time because of the :
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultlst)) { ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the SQL query like this:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM uploaded WHERE sbid = $newid AND subject = '{$row['en']}'";`

However, it is usually not safe to build SQL query like this because it might be vulnarable to [SQL injection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).